# Last trailing blank PDF page gets added, need to remove

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, html, renderas

I have below last element and trying to remove the trailing blank pdf page added. It is not working. Can someone please let me know how to deal with it?

**Apex Page**

*Last element*

```
    .....<td width="50%" style="text-align:center;"><div style="margin:auto;page-break-after: auto;"><img src="{!$Resource.Image}" width="100" 

height="20"/></div> </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me here.

Comment: Please , accept below answer if it help to solve issue. Else comment likewise so that we can improve it as required.

Answer (score 2):

I also once gone through it, and done with following solution. Try this out.

```
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" />    
<apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="cse"> 
      <!-- apex:OutputText value="{!cnt}"/ -->
     <div style="{!if(cnt < 1, 'page-break-before:avoid;','page-break-before:always;')}">
     <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/> .... .... </div> 
 </apex:repeat>
```